# How do I avoid clicking the button twice in order to fire an event in jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

When I click a button once,I'm unable to fire an event.Double clicking of a button is making my event to fire.

I've used angular js and jQuery over here.I'm not getting,where I'm going wrong.Can any one please help me out regarding this issue ...

My js code:

```
   var app = angular
            .module('Home', [ 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngRoute' ]);
    app.config([ '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/basic', {
            controller : 'Sample',
            templateUrl : 'html/basic.html'
        }).when('/features', {
            controller : 'Sample',
            templateUrl : 'html/basic.html'
        })
    } ]);
    app.controller('Sample', function($scope) {

        $scope.getFilenameFromPath = function(filename) {
                return filename.split("/")[1].split(".")[0];
        }

            $('#hideDiv').click(function() {
                    $('#diva').hide();
            })

    });
```

My html code:

```
<a  href="#/basic"><button id="hideDiv" style="margin-left: 22px; background-color: #73AD21">Basic</button></a>

<a href="#/features"><button id="showDiv" style="margin-left: 22px; background-color: #73AD21">+Features</button></a>



    <div id="diva" class="subdiv">
     <div style="margin-top: 15px; display: inline-block"
                ng-repeat="advanceimage in advanceimages">
      <img width=40 height=50 style="margin-left: 12px;" ng-src="{{advanceimage}}" /> 
      <br>
      <span style="margin-left: 12px;">{{getFilenameFromPath(advanceimage)}}</span>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use [`ngHide`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) or [`ngShow`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)?

Comment: Actually,I've tried using ng-hide and ng-show.But,I'm unable to do it.I'm using the same controller and same html page here.when I click the "Basic" button,I should hide "diva" and onclick of a "Features" button should show  "diva"

Comment: For the both buttons,I can only  either hide the div (or) show a div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to use `ngHide`:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.hideDiva = false;
  $scope.toggle = function() {
    $scope.hideDiva = !$scope.hideDiva;
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.8"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <button ng-click="toggle()">Hide/show</button>
  <div>
    <img ng-hide="hideDiva" src="http://media.mydogspace.com.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/puppy-500x350.jpg">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

If you have any questions about it just let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Try to investigate `debounce` or `throttle` technic - http://underscorejs.org/#debounce or http://underscorejs.org/#throttle .

> **Throttle** - Creates and returns a new, throttled version of the passed function, that, when invoked repeatedly, will only actually call the original function at most once per every wait milliseconds. Useful for rate-limiting events that occur faster than you can keep up with.